# HTTPS pictures randomly NOT loading TYPO3

Tags: android, internet-explorer, https, typo3

I'm using TYPO3 and have this strange problem of pictures randomly not showing up on all pages. I checked the httaccess, aswell as the https certificate, it's all set up right. Before i switched over to https i had no problems. When i download the website in Chrome and upload it back to the server with a folder containg all the files it works perfectly on all devices. If i open the website generated by TYPO3 it let's images dissapear, every time i reload it does it with different pictures and the css code  sometimes doesn't load either. I also get https errors like:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.com/index.php?id=266' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://test.com/icons_newsletter/google.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

But it is served via https, the whole content.

It does that only on Android Standard Browsers (Galaxy s3 for example) aswell as Internet Explorer 9-10 on Windows Desktop machines. Chrome shows it fine, but it shows the https errors in the console, so. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you cleared all caches (in the install tool, if it is TYPO3 6.2)? Is `config.baseUrl` set? If so, try to remove it and set `config.absRefPrefix = /` instead.

Comment: I'm under 6.1 and i cleared the cache, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see different browsers threads mixed content different ways. You need to check why browser tries to get images via `http` while you're in `https` mode, as Jost mentioned most probably you are using `baseURL` with `http://test.com/` change it to `https://test.com/` or even better `//test.com/`.

On the other hand as Jost also mentioned you can avoid `baseURL` at all in favor of `config.absRefPrefix` - this is way I use successfully on all installations from year. But keep in mind that might be some older extensions in TER which requires `baseURL` so you need to check your case step-by-step.

Finally check if given `src` attr isn't absoulte path for some reason, if it is, try to change it (depending on what creates these paths)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to biesior's comment: We had the phenomenon that even though the baseUrl was set and a permanent redirect from http to https via .htaccess was configured, some Internet Explorer clients still tried to access content via http because they skipped the .htaccess redirect for no obvious reason. We finally managed to fix that problem by setting [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Configure CORS
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.mydomain.tld"
    Header always append Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://www.mydomain.tld"
</IfModule>
```